# Авторизация на Stackoverflow

Tags: c#, post, авторизация

Скажите пожалуйста как мне сделать авторизацию на StackOverflow? Я вот остановился на параметре "fkey", от куда мне его брать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из объекта `StackExchange`: `StackExchange.options.user.fkey`.

Но лучше пользоваться [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

Comment: Блин, Документация по API на инглише, не чего не понятно :(

Comment: Можете подсказать как сделать это при помощи API?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, там достаточно легко, я не очень знаю английский, но разобрался за пару часов (потом оказалось что проблема не в языке, а в устаревшем примере).

Comment: А если стандартным постом работать, то мне потом сохранять cookie?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, подсказать не могу, т.к. не знаю шарп. Алгоритм - обычный, в общем-то, OAuth2 - отправляете запрос, они запрашивают у пользователя разрешение и возвращают Вам токен доступа.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, можно и обычным клиентом прикинутся, но это как-то... в лоб, как в 90-тых :)

Comment: А `OAuth` это какая-то библиотека ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38982/discussion-between-other-and-alex-rudenkiy).